# CakePHP 3 - $this->request->getData when reading POST arrays

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3 I can access a POST variable such as `start` like this:

`$this->request->getData('start')`

If my POST value is in the form of an array - in plain PHP such as `$_POST['order'][3]['column']` I can access it in Cake like this:

`$this->request['data']['order'][3]['column']`

Is this the correct (or only) way to do this, or should you also be able to use `getData()` to access it?

Comment: Use the OO way to access things. There are reasons why the interfaces exists to access data through them. See https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Http.ServerRequest.html#_getData

Comment: Ok, but how could I access something that's in an array format as per my example (`['order'][3]['column']`)? I get how you do it for simple items where you just pass the name as a string to `getData` but that doesn't work for arrays, or so it seems?

Comment: As the API doc tells you `Allows you to use Hash::get() compatible paths.` so check https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Utility.Hash.html#_get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the OO way to access things. There are reasons why the interfaces exists to access data through them. See [getData()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Http.ServerRequest.html#_getD%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bata).

```
// As array
$this->request->getData('order')[3]['column'];

// https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Utility.Hash.html#_get
$this->request->getData('order.3.column');
```